# Binding Images to Image placeholder in repeater

Tags: nativescript

I have a repeater that loads info from SQLite and works well. The user has options to take photos which are stored both in their photo library and in a temp folder. On reloading the page I need to reload the images to for a sliding gallery of thumbnails under the relevant section in the repeater.

The Image repeater is defined as

```
  <Repeater items="{{ images }}" id="{{ repeaterphotoid }}">
  <Repeater.itemTemplate>
    <Image src="{{localurl}}" width="75" height="75" visibility="{{photoevidence === 'y' ? 'visible' : 'collapse'}}" />
  </Repeater.itemTemplate>
</Repeater>
```

And my code is

```
   exports.takePic = function(args){
     var page = args.object;
    camera.requestPermissions().then(
    function success(){
       var livesite = appSettings.getString("livesite");
       var images=[];
       var whichcamera = args.object;
        var options = {saveToGallery: true, keepAspectRation: true, height: 1024 };
        var gallery = args.object.page.getViewById("images-"+whichcamera.id);
        var source = new imageSourceModule.ImageSource();
        camera.takePicture(options).then(function(imageAsset){
            var img = new imageModule.Image();
            source.fromAsset(imageAsset).then((imageSource) => {
                var auditDB = new sqlite("my.db", function(err, db){
                    if (err){
                            alert("Failed to open the database", err);
                        } else {
                var tempfilename = livesite+"-"+whichcamera.qid+"-";
                db.all("SELECT filename FROM images WHERE filename LIKE '"+tempfilename+"%'").then(rows =>{
                    //console.log("Images rows="+rows.length+1);
                    if (rows.length == 0){
                        imageCount = 1;
                    }
                    else
                        {
                            imageCount = rows.length+1;
                        }
                var livesite = appSettings.getString("livesite");
               // var path = filesystem.path.join(filesystem.knownFolders.documants().path,"photos")
                var folder = filesystem.knownFolders.documents();
                var filename = livesite+"-"+whichcamera.qid+"-"+imageCount+".jpg";
                var imgPath = filesystem.path.join(folder.path,filename);
                var saved = imageSource.saveToFile(imgPath,"jpg");
                if (saved){
                            var livesite = appSettings.getString("livesite");
                            var liveaudit = appSettings.getString("liveaudit");
                            db.execSQL("INSERT INTO images (localurl,remoteurl,syncd,siteid,filename,question) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?)",[imgPath,'-','n',livesite,filename,whichcamera.qid])
                            var imageList = [];
                    var tempfilename = livesite+"-"+whichcamera.qid+"-";
                            var imageSQL = "SELECT localurl,remoteurl,filename FROM images WHERE filename LIKE '"+tempfilename+"%'";
                            db.all(imageSQL).then(rows =>{
                                for (var row in rows) {
                                    imageList.push({
                                        localurl: rows[row][0],
                                        filename: rows[row][2]
                                    });
                                }
                                const imagesource = fromObject({
                                images: imageList
                                    });
                                imagesource.set = ("images", imageList);
                                var imageholder = args.object.page.getViewById("repeat_"+whichcamera.id);   
                                imageholder.bindingContext = imagesource;
                            });
                            };
                });

                    };

                });
            });
        }).catch(function (err) {
            alert("Camera Error "+err.message);
        })
      //alert("Taking Pic with camera "+whichcamera.id); 
    },
        function failure(){
          alert("You must allow this app access to the camera and your photos library.")  
        });   
}
```

Binding to the questions works as expected but I cannot bind the images to the image repeater, nothing happens. Obviously missing something but going code blind.

Comment: Can you show us couple sample values for `localurl`? Also your Observable contains the property `imageList` but you are binding it with `images`?

Comment: localurl is the path to the locally saved image:-/Users/nick/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/6F92BA88-A124-4FC8-9918-8CB96FCDFE3C/data/Containers/Data/Application/C8B2EAF4-3CD9-4AC7-BB29-420BAD7B3A04/Documents/Birmingham-9-1.jpg stored before I upload to the remote server.

Comment: You are not supposed to save absolute path of image, always store the relative path, because over updates iOS will assign new UUID for your app and the base path will be different from previous one. If you still have issues, please share a complete Playground sample.

Comment: These are only temporary images which are deleted after they are uploaded but I see your point.

Comment: OK here is my full code for taking a picture, saving it and storing the path in a SQLite DB. Ive updated the code above to show the complete take pic code. I have multiple cameras on the page each given a unique ID in a repeater. I use the camera ID to identify which to bind to, but still cannot get it to work.